# Не получается спарсить JSON массив в массиве

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, парсер

Есть JSON:

```
    {
        "CameraScen":[
                {
                    "SceneName" : "PathAll",
                    "Scenario": [
                        {
                            "timeAction": 5,
                            "type":"circle",
                            "comment":"захватил цель."
                        },
                        {
                            "timeAction": 10,
                            "type":"waypoint",
                            "comment":"летит над колоной."
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SceneName" : "ShellingMovement",
                    "Scenario": [
                        {
                            "timeAction": 10,
                            "type":"waypoint",
                            "comment":"летит над колоной."
                        },
                        {
                            "timeAction": 10,
                            "type":"waypoint",
                            "comment":"летит над колоной."
                        }
                    ]
                }
        ]
    }
```

Мне надо спарсить эту структуру, я делаю так :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

//using  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class ScenarioCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    private float startTime;
    public CameraScen[] SCCam;

    void  Awake () {

        startTime = Time.time;
        getCameraScenarioAll ();

    }

    void Update () {

        float t = Time.time - startTime;
        int timeINT = (int)(t % 60);

    }

    public void getCameraScenarioAll() {

        RootObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath+ "/Scene/settingscamer.json"));

        for (int i=0;i<o.CameraScen.Count;i++) {
            Debug.Log (o.CameraScen[i].SceneName);

            List<Scenario> tempScenario = o.CameraScen [i].Scenar;

            for(int j=0;j<tempScenario.Count;j++) {

                Debug.Log (tempScenario[j].timeAction);
                Debug.Log (tempScenario[j].type);
                Debug.Log (tempScenario[j].comment);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public int timeAction { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}

public class CameraScen
{
    public string SceneName { get; set; }
    public List<Scenario> Scenar { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<CameraScen> CameraScen { get; set; }
}
```

Но ошибка :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ScenarioCamera.Awake () (at Assets/Scene/ScenarioCamera.cs:15)
```

36-ая СТРОКА Это: `for(int j=0;j<tempScenario.Count;j++) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Копируете ваш JSON в буфер
2. Открываете студию
3. В студии есть `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes`

Получаем

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Camera[] Camera { get; set; }
}

public class Camera
{
    public string SceneName { get; set; }
    public Scenario[] Scenario { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public int timeAction { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}
```

Видим, что тут главный объект выглядит так:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Camera[] Camera { get; set; }
}
```

Ваш объект, в который вы пытаетесь десериализовать выглядит так

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Scenes<T>
{
    public T[] Scene;
}
```

То есть у вашего корневого объекта поле вместо свойства да ещё и не с тем названием. Попробуйте

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Scenes<T>
{
    public T[] Camera {get;set};
}
```

**UPD**

Я взял вашу строку

```
string str = @"   {
    ""CameraScen"":[
            {
                ""SceneName"" : ""PathAll"",
                ""Scenario"": [
                    {
                        ""timeAction"": 5,
                        ""type"":""circle"",
                        ""comment"":""захватил цель.""
                    },
                    {
                        ""timeAction"": 10,
                        ""type"":""waypoint"",
                        ""comment"":""летит над колоной.""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                ""SceneName"" : ""ShellingMovement"",
                ""Scenario"": [
                    {
                        ""timeAction"": 10,
                        ""type"":""waypoint"",
                        ""comment"":""летит над колоной.""
                    },
                    {
                        ""timeAction"": 10,
                        ""type"":""waypoint"",
                        ""comment"":""летит над колоной.""
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}";
```

Взял ваши классы

```
public class Scenario
{
    public int timeAction { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}

public class CameraScen
{
    public string SceneName { get; set; }
    public List<Scenario> Scenario { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<CameraScen> CameraScen { get; set; }
}
```

Ваш класс камеры

```
public class JsonCamera
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Scenes<T> wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Scenes<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.CameraScen;
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Scenes<T>
    {
        public T[] CameraScen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

С камерой только мне пришлось взять другой сериализатор - JSON.NET, так как у меня нет Unity.

После я вял ваш метод

```
public CameraScen[] getCameraScenarioAll()
{
    CameraScen[] SCCamTemp = JsonCamera.FromJson<CameraScen>(str);
    if (SCCamTemp != null)
    {
        return SCCamTemp;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Ваш код

```
var SCCam = getCameraScenarioAll();
for (int i = 0; i < SCCam.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SCCam[i].SceneName);
}
```

И на выводе у меня всё работает

```
PathAll
ShellingMovement
```

Потому, мне кажется, вам надо заняться отладкой вашего приложения, так как в том виде что сейчас всё должно работать.

Comment: Тут надо переписать public class JsonCamera. Только я пока не пойму  как . Ваш ответ не информативный . В студия я не пишу , делая в Mono. Может там и есть модуль который обрабатывает  json, но это не мой вариант. Ради того чтоб json спарсить я её не буду устанавливать + там ещё и библиотеки надо будет подтянуть , скорей всего

Comment: @IvanTriumphov я вам дал прямо классы, которые можно пользовать для десериализации. Ну нет у вас студии - не проблема, классы можно и [онлайн сгенерировать](http://json2csharp.com/). Если этот ответ не информативный, то я не знаю, что для вас информативно.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov у вас просто не совпадает структура класса со структурой JSON'а, о чем вам и сказали.

Comment: @tym32167 Я попробую сгенерировать класс по вашей ссылке, прочитаю ещё ваш ответ и вникну. Поторопился отписаться . Если поможет отмечу как правильный

Comment: @IvanTriumphov я уже все сгенерировал за вас, вам надо только сравнить классы из моего ответа с вашими классами, найти разницу и устранить её.

Comment: не помогло я изменил код в вопросе . Надо переделать думаю ещё JsonCamera.FromJson<CameraScen> Сейчса ошибка :NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @IvanTriumphov я обновил ответ с вашими классами, у меня все отработало. Вам, видимо, придется заняться отладкой вашего кода. Может вы файл не тот грузите или ещё что то не так делаете.

Comment: Мне надо было не изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовые библиотеки. Спасибо за ответ . Получилось спарсить тоже

Comment: Подключил библиотеку https://gist.github.com/onionmk2/d2e3e4cca27a37a89796e084e05de212

Comment: У меня тоже получилось первый объект спарсить а вот со вторым :NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Сейчас обновлю код в вопросе на 36 строке ошибка

Comment: Как второй объект"Scenario" еще спарсить?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov вы назвали свойство вот так `public List<Scenario> Scenar { get; set; }`, а  в JSON оно называется `"Scenario"`, вам надо переименовать свойство в соответствии с JSON

Comment: `Мне надо было не изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовые библиотеки.` в вашем коде нет веловипедов, вы тут не изобретаете ничего, вы учитесь использовать готовые библиотеки правильно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97142/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-tym32167).

Comment: @IvanTriumphov я на работе не могу в чат. Я отвечать то особо времени не имею

Comment: Разобрался спасибо